# Is the theory of real closed fields finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: model-theory

I don't know if this has been asked before, but is the theory of real closed fields $(F;+,-,*,0,1,<)$ finitely axiomatizable? The usual axiomatization is to take the axioms for ordered fields and add an axiom stating that every positive number has a square root and an axiom schema stating that every odd-degree polynomial has a root. I am wondering if this axiomatization can be replaced by a finite one, and if not, the proof that it can not.

Comment: No, see [Jensen, Model Theoretic Algebra, p. 22](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Model_Theoretic_Algebra_With_Particular/yMz9fW8JgiwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=real+closed+fields+is+finitely+axiomatizable&pg=PA21&printsec=frontcover). That every odd degree polynomial has a root needs an axiom schema, so it is recursively but no finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: @Conifold You should turn your comment into an answer